# dynamically created content in JavaScript lost on refresh page MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, page-refresh, dynamic-content

I have a page where I create session tab & 2 sub tabs inside session tab with multiple controls inside sub tab. This happens on some events. In this case user can have multiple session tabs if he has multiple events. I am creating these tabs in java script when user receive event with that specific condition.
Issue is when user click on refresh button all tabs vanishes. How can I maintain  states / tabs even if user clicks on refresh button.

Comment: Yes, that's a natural behavior. After the refreshed browser shows only the code that is received from the server.

Comment: How can I avoid it ?  Is there any way where I can store these details and show again to user?

Comment: Typically, it's dynamic because we don't want to be there all the time. For some reason, if you have to go to the server and get new data before completing the work from that page. Use AJAX calls. But if the user refreshes then changes would go. There are ways to store them, but I wouldn't recommend storing the new HTML content and load on page reload

Comment: It is expected that user should not refresh page while working. But we do not have control over user behavior.  Dynamic content is expected to disappear/dispose when user click on button inside dynamic content.  I need to store/restore  these  details in case user click on refresh button.  Else I need to use popup for this dynamic content  where user will not have refresh button which is not requirement here. Appreciate if you can guide me to store these content till user clicks dispose button.  It is Asp.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a flag that sets to true when new content is modified. If the user is trying to leave/refresh you can warn using onunload/onbeforeunload

```
var _isDirty = false;
//Set this flag to true when you are making changes
 _isDirty = true;
```

hook the method and check with the user, if he/she really wants to refresh

```
function confirmWinClose() {
 var confirmClose = confirm('Are you sure you want to refresh/leave?');
 return confirmClose;
}

window.onbeforeunload = confirmWinClose();
```